# dispatch_async with NSOperation queue

Tags: ios

I am using NSOperation queue for parsing a url and loading UITableview after complete, here is my code, I am using dispatch_async within NSOperation queue,my question is ,can I use this kind of code,is this approach wrong?

```
 queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
 NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                     selector:@selector(loadDataWithOperation) object:nil];
      [queue addOperation:operation];

 - (void) loadDataWithOperation {

   __block NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

        NSURL *dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"url"]];
        NSError *err=nil;
        data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:dataURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&err];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            NSError *err=nil;

            NSDictionary *response_login;


            if(!err)
            {
                [bookingTime removeAllObjects];
                [duration removeAllObjects];
                [guestNumber removeAllObjects];
                [status removeAllObjects];

                response_login = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&err];
                 NSArray *TimeSlotList=[[response_login  objectForKey:@"ResultInfo"]objectForKey:@"TimeSlotList"];

                if( [TimeSlotList count]>0 )
                {
                    for(NSDictionary *dict in TimeSlotList)
                    {

                        [bookingTime addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"BookingTime"]];
                        [duration addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"Duration"]];
                        [status addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"IsBlocked"]]];
                         [guestNumber addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"AvailCount"]];


                    }


                    [self.view addSubview:bookingDetails];
                    [self.bookingDetails reloadData];
                }
                else
                {

                    res1.text=@"No available timeslot Found";
                    [self.view addSubview:res];

                }
            }


        });
    });
```

}

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Using the NSOperationQueue in this way seems quite pointless.

You also seem to have the habit of accessing instance variables directly instead of accessors. You should start all instance variables with an underscore character to make this very visible to anyone reading the code. Using an instance variable instead of an accessor may lead to bugs that are very hard to find.